# Flask: using app as an attribute and accessing decorators

Tags: python, flask

using the python flask module, i would like to have the

```
app = flask.Flask(__name__)
```

as a attribute of a class:

```
class Handler(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.datastores = {}
        self.websocket_queue = gevent.queue.JoinableQueue()
        self.app = flask.Flask(__name__)
```

the problem is how to access decorators then?

```
    @self.app.route('/socket.io/<path:remaining>')
    def socketio(self, remaining):
```

That generates the error `NameError: name 'self' is not defined`
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could try to use [Flask-Classy](http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Classy/) as it provides an easy way to use classes with [Python-Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/).

Answer (score 2):

It depends - if you are adding handlers inside of a method of the `Handler` class it should work without issue:

```
def add_routes(self):
    @self.app.route("/some/route")
    def some_route():
        return "At some route"
```

If you are attempting to add routes outside of `Handler` you will need to use a reference to your `Handler` instance:

```
handler = Handler()

@handler.app.route("/some/route")
def some_route():
    return "At some route"
```

Comment: i want handlers inside `Handler` so should I define all my methods inside `add_routes` methods?

Comment: @Mermoz - inside of whatever method or combinations of methods make sense for your application.